# Need more pseudo terminals

Tags: terminal

I'm running tmux and creating many sessions to various servers. After opening 128, I can no longer open new ones, or open new tabs in Terminal. The error messages is:

```
forkpty: Device not configured
Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.
```

Is there any way I can increase the number of ptys?

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what version of OS X you're running, and what kind of Mac, and particularly, how much RAM you have installed.

Comment: I'm using 10.8.2 and have 8gb of RAM, which should be more than enough to open thousands of ssh sessions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Tested on OS X 10.8.2; other releases may be slightly different.)

You can change the system’s limit on ptys with the *sysctl* command.

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.tty.ptmx_max=255
```

This should immediately let you open more ptys.

To set this automatically after each reboot, put the following line in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
kern.tty.ptmx_max=255
```

(Note: I did not try this, but, from a look at the source code, it looks like *launchd* does process this file.)

This file may not exist; if you have to create it, you should probably be sure it has restricted ownership and permissions:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo chmod 644 /etc/sysctl.conf
```

---

Eventually, you may run into some other per-process or per-user resource limits (e.g. total number of processes per user, and total number of open file descriptors per process).

Comment: Eventually got to test this, works great, thanks. For the record, I couldn't set this above 999, but that will do for now.

Comment: This allows me to open up to 169 ptys, but not more. `sudo sysctl kern.tty.ptmx_max` returns `999` which is correct. Anything I'm missing on this one?

Comment: @ubuntudroid: You might be running into a limit on the number of open files (`ulimit` in *bash*). These kinds of limits are inherited from parent processes, so to change it for *tmux* you will need to change it in (e.g.) a shell and then restart your *tmux* server. To make the change “persistent”, try a [`launchctl.conf`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.conf.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.conf) that uses a [`limit` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).

Comment: Whenever inside tmux on my Mac (10.9.4) i noticed `ulimit -a` reported a 256 file descriptor limit. Calling `ulimit -n 2000` totally worked though.

Answer (score 0):

I had new terminal windows failing with

```
[forkpty: Too many open files]
[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

even though I had `kern.tty.ptmx_max: 511` (the default setting for my computer running Catalina with 64 GiB memory). I also had `kern.maxfilesperproc: 98304` so I knew it was not that limit, either.

I thought it might be `ulimit` since `ulimit -n` was 256, but discounted that because `lsof -c Terminal | wc` was 315, well over 256. Turns out it *was* `ulimit` but `lsof` lists more files than `ulimit` limits. I will skip the explanation, but what you want to look at is

```
lsof -X -c Terminal | wc
```

The `-X` limits `lsof` to showing just file descriptors, which what `ulimit` limits. That was 257 (the 256 limit, plus a header line in the `lsof` output).

So, in addition to the 2 `sysctl` settings, I needed to adjust the default `ulimit` with `launchctl`. That turns out to be harder than you would expect.

The command to use to view the `ulimit` soft and hard limits on the number of open files is `launchctl limit maxfiles` which on my computer output

```
maxfiles    256           unlimited
```

The command to change the limits is `launchctl limit maxfiles <softlimit> <hardlimit>` but you cannot set the hard limit to "unlimited" because [the kernel converts "unlimited" to 10240](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366319/21703). If you leave out the hard limit, it is set to the same as the soft limit, which is even worse. So what I did was use the value from `sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc` as the hard limit. I ran

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1001 98304
```

Well, that took care of `ulimit`, but unfortunately, it also reset the kernel parameters:

```
kern.maxfiles: 98304
kern.maxfilesperproc: 1001
```

which is definitely ***not*** what I wanted. I wanted the soft limit to change the default ulimit and the hard limit to change `kern.maxfilesperproc` but instead the soft limit changed `kern.maxfilesperproc` and the hard limit changed `kern.maxfiles`. So I ran it again, restoring the previous values from the kernel

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 98304 196608
```

This sets the `ulimit` way too high, but I think that is better than setting the kernel limit too low.

These changes also do not persist after reboot. To get them to persist, now that `/etc/launchd.conf` no longer works, consider these solutions for [persisting a single setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311753/712765) or [restoring the launchd.conf behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965923/712765).