# How to set kernel state to unbounded ("unlimited") value using sysctl?

Tags: macos, kernel

I want to set `kern.maxfiles` kernel state to unbounded value using `sysctl`.

However, the commands `sysctl kern.maxfiles=unlimited` yields an error (not an integer), while I'm not sure of the sematics of `sysctl kern.maxfiles=-1` (cannot find any documentation).

Anyone knows?

Comment: I am going to explain this in details on your other question (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366187/why-does-setting-the-hard-limit-for-maxfiles-to-unlimited-using-launchctl-lim), i am just finishing the writeup with examples.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my answer there, with MacOS Kernel Source code and launchctl source code, showing why it is impossible to set the value 'unlimited'.